# Javascript only works locally but doesn't work on live site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm coding a website and it works fine locally but when I test it live, it doesn't work exactly the same:
http://keirabui.com/kairos2/ - the cranes should disappear faster which will reveal the animation of the round gold logo - like this: https://dribbble.com/shots/2057062-Heartbeat

The script for the crane fading out is:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".craneloader").delay(2200).fadeOut(1000);
})
```

Also the beating heart is not clickable at all in Firefox but works fine in Chrome and Safari. Anyone know why?

Comment: Open Chrome's developer tools, load your site, and look at the network and console tabs.

Comment: Turned out it was because of the fonts script.. Thank you! (the animation is still different in Firefox though.. ). Do you happen to know why the beating heart is not clickable in Firefox?

Comment: Firefox might not be working because there is a typo on the first list item in your map code: onfocus="blur()";....there is a semicolon outside of the quotes.

Comment: You are also getting error about the coordinates.

Comment: I figured it out. If <map> has any <a> children Firefox will ignore whole <map> element. Thanks guys!! :)